# I try to execute a function inside a package. But I got this error 'FUNC_RET_NEWSAL' is not a procedure or is undefined

Tags: oracle, plsql

**1.This Is my package specification**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_EMP IS
 
   V_INC_PRECENT HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE;
   
   FUNCTION FUNC_RET_INCRE(P_EMP_ID HR.EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE)
     RETURN NUMBER;
     
   FUNCTION FUNC_RET_NEWSAL(P_EMP_ID HR.EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE)
     RETURN NUMBER;
     
   PROCEDURE PROC_GET_NAMES(P_EMP   IN HR.EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
                            P_FNAME OUT HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
                            P_LNAME OUT HR.EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%TYPE);
                            
   FUNCTION FUNC_RET_FULLNAME(P_FNAME HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
                              P_LNAME HR.EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%TYPE)
     RETURN HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
     
 END PKG_EMP
```

**2.The is package body,**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_EMP IS
  FUNCTION FUNC_RET_INCRE(P_EMP_ID HR.EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE) ---calculate increment percentage
   RETURN NUMBER IS
    V_SALARY  HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
    V_PCT     NUMBER;
    V_DEPT_ID HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE;
  
  BEGIN
    SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID
      INTO V_DEPT_ID
      FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
     WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = P_EMP_ID;
  
    V_PCT := V_DEPT_ID / 100;
    RETURN V_PCT;
  END FUNC_RET_INCRE;

  FUNCTION FUNC_RET_NEWSAL(P_EMP_ID HR.EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE) --- display new salary using previous 
  FUNCTION ---
  RETURN NUMBER IS
    V_SALARY HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
    V_PCT    NUMBER;
  
    V_NEW_SAL HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
  BEGIN
  
    SELECT SALARY
      INTO V_SALARY
      FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
     WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = P_EMP_ID;
    V_INC_PRECENT := FUNC_RET_INCRE(V_EMP_ID);
    V_NEW_SAL     := V_SALARY + V_INC_PRECENT;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_NEW_SAL);
    RETURN V_NEW_SAL;
  END FUNC_RET_NEWSAL;

  PROCEDURE PROC_GET_NAMES(P_EMP   IN HR.EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
                           P_FNAME OUT HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
                           P_LNAME OUT HR.EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%TYPE) ---- get names separately
   IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
      INTO P_FNAME, P_LNAME
      FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
     WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = P_EMP;
  END PROC_GET_NAMES;

  FUNCTION FUNC_RET_FULLNAME(P_FNAME HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
                             P_LNAME HR.EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%TYPE)
    RETURN HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE IS
    EMP_FULL_NAME HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(P_FNAME, ' '), P_LNAME)
      INTO EMP_FULL_NAME
      FROM HR.EMPLOYEES;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(EMP_FULL_NAME);
    RETURN EMP_FULL_NAME;
  END FUNC_RET_FULLNAME;
END PKG_EMP;
```

**3.when I try to execute it,**

```
EXEC pkg_emp. func_ret_newsal(105);
```

I got the error

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>
> PLS-00221: 'FUNC_RET_NEWSAL' is not a procedure or is undefined

Answer (score 1):

as the error message also tells you, function is not a procedure.
The difference between function and procedure is that a function always returns a value.

you have to assign this value to a variable

**function call:**

```
declare
  var number; -- if your funtion returns a number
begin
  var := my_func();
end;
/
```

**procedure call:**

```
begin
  my_proc();
end;
/
```

---

so in your case, if you want to call a funtion, you need a variable to assign a return value

```
declare
  v number; -- if your funtion returns a number
begin
  v := pkg_emp. func_ret_newsal(105);
end;
```

or in sqlplus

```
sql> var v number

sql> begin
  2  select pkg_emp.func_ret_newsal(105) into :v from dual;
  3  end;
  4  /
```

or

```
EXEC DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(pkg_emp.func_ret_newsal(105));
```